# How does Quetzalcoatl's legendary ability interact with Creeping Death?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

[Quetzalcoatl](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/quetzalcoatl) has an interesting legendary ability:

> Locust Swarm and Haunt now deal their damage in half of the normal duration.

[Creeping Death](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/witch-doctor/passive/creeping-death) is a new Witch Doctor passive that also affects Locust Swarm and Haunt:

> Your Haunt, Locust Swarm and the damage amplification from Piranhas last almost forever.

The former is nice because the DoT damages enemies twice as fast. The latter is nice because the DoT lasts forever and you don't have to reapply over and over. If you have both, what is the end result? Does the DoT do damage twice as quickly *and* last forever? Is one of the bonuses neglected in favor of the other?

Comment: Better pair Creeping Death with a [Raiment of Jade Harvester](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/jade-harvesters-wisdom) set bonus. Yes, it does work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Almost forever", where Creeping Death is concerned, is 5 minutes.

This does work. The result is an DoT which deals double the damage per tick and lasts 150 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Creeping Death last 1 hour

http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Creeping_Death

> Creeping Death Passive The duration of Locust Swarm, Haunt and damage
>   amplification of Piranhas increases to 3600 seconds (or until the
>   Witch Doctor dies or ventures into another level, or at least 200
>   yards away).
>
> There are some terrors that cannot be outrun. Bit by bit, second by
>   second, they consume you.

Maybe it has changed. But I think now it last 1 hour.